# Does Kotlin have pointers?

Tags: pointers, kotlin

Does Kotlin have pointers? 
If yes,

1. How to increment a Pointer?
2. How to decrement a Pointer?
3. How to do Pointer Comparisons?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It has references, and it doesn't support pointer arithmetic (so you can't increment or decrement).

Note that the only thing that "having pointers" allows you is the ability to create a pointer and to dereference it.

The closest thing to a "pointer comparison" is referential equality, which is performed with the `===` operator.

Answer (score 4):

There is no pointers in *Kotlin* for low-level processing as *C*.

However, it's possible emulate pointers in high-level programming.

For low-level programming it is necessary using special  system APIs to simulate arrays in memories, that exists  in *Windows*, `Linux`, etc. Read about memory mapped files [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2898365/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net.html) and [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/memorymapped-file-and-io-in-java.html). Java [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849609/how-to-manipulate-memory-from-java-with-jna-on-windows) library to read and write directly in memory.

Single types (numeric, string and boolean) are values, however, other types  are references (high level pointers) in *Kotlin*, that one can compare, assign, etc.

If one needs increment or decrement pointers, just encapsulate the desired data package into a array

For simulate pointers to simple values it just wrap the value in a class:

```
data class pStr (   // Pointer to a String
  var s:String=""
)

fun main() {
 var st=pStr("banana")
 var tt=st
 tt.s = "melon"
 println(st.s) // display "melon"

 var s:String = "banana"
 var t:String = s
 t.s = "melon"
 println(s.s) // display "banana"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this question while googling over some interesting code I found and thought that I would contribute my own proverbial "two cents". So Kotlin does have an operator which might be confused as a pointer, based on syntax, the spread operator. The [spread operator](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/varargs-spread-operator) is often used to pass an array as a `vararg` parameter.

For example, one might see something like the following line of code which looks suspiciously like the use of a pointer:

```
val process = ProcessBuilder(*args.toTypedArray()).start()
```

This line isn't calling the `toTypedArray()` method on a pointer to the `args` array, as you might expect if you come from a C/C++ background like me. Rather, this code is actually just calling the `toTypedArray()` method on the `args` array (as one would expect) and then passing the elements of the array as an arbitrary number of `varargs` arguments. Without the spread operator (i.e. `*`), a single argument would be passed, which would be the typed `args` array, itself.

That's the key difference: the spread operator enables the developer to pass the elements of the array as a list of `varargs` as opposed to passing a pointer to the array, itself, as a single argument.

I hope that helps.